# How powermockit mocks a private method

Tags: classloader, powermock

Here, I want to understand the internals of Powermockito.  How does it mock a private method?
I thought that it uses a new class loader to create a different copy of the class, but when I tried to do the same, I got a runtime exception showing that the 2 classes (one originally created by System class loader) and the one I passed are of different versions.

```
package com.concretepage.lang;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
    NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
    CustomClassLoaderDemo loader = new CustomClassLoaderDemo();
    Class<?> c = loader.findClass("com.concretepage.lang.Test");
    Object ob = c.newInstance();
    Method md = c.getMethod("show");
    md.invoke(ob);
    System.out.println(c.getClassLoader());
    System.out.println(ob.getClass().getClassLoader());


    ((com.concretepage.lang.Test)ob).show();
    Test c2 = new Test();

    System.out.println(c2.getClass().getClassLoader());

    Class<?> cClass = Class.forName("com.concretepage.lang.Test");
    System.out.println(cClass.getClassLoader());

    java.net.URLClassLoader urlLoader =  java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("File://c//Users//dell//eclipse-workspace//DeemTest//src")}, loader); 
    Class<?> testRemoteClazz = urlLoader.loadClass("com.concretepage.lang.Test");

    Object obUrl = testRemoteClazz.newInstance();
    Method mdUrl = testRemoteClazz.getMethod("show");
    mdUrl.invoke(obUrl);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your unit test is une the same package path, you may try to pass your methods in protected.

Example :

app package => myapp.services.impl
test package => myapp.serviceS.impl

Then with the same package name, the method protected will be reachable for the test.
If you can't make that, you should pass the method to public, but i don't think that's your objective... Proceted is in general a good solution.